# Return data even if not found in IN clause - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a user table I am searching with phone number in this case two phone number is exist in my table one is not exist but I want that it should return 3 ROW with value 'exists' 'exist' and 'not exist' I tried this but it not work

```
SELECT IFNULL(id ,'exists')
FROM users
WHERE phone_no IN ("581850412","554537361","9999999990") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put the expected phone numbers in a derived table that you can then `left join` with the original table:

```
select
    p.phone_no
    case when u.phone_no is null then 'not exists' else 'exists' end 
from (
    select '581850412' phone_no
    union all select '554537361'
    union all select '9999999990'
) p
left join users u on u.phone_no = p.phone_no
```

Alternatively, you can put the results in columns with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    case when max(phone_no = '581850412')  = 1 then 'exists' else 'not exists' end has_581850412,
    case when max(phone_no = '554537361')  = 1 then 'exists' else 'not exists' end has_554537361,
    case when max(phone_no = '9999999990') = 1 then 'exists' else 'not exists' end has_9999999990
from users
```

Comment: Can you do `CASE WHEN p.phone_no IN (...) THEN 'exists' ELSE 'not exists' END` in the select clause? Then you don't need the join at all, just a query on `users`

Comment: @Pointy: if you want results as rows, this is the way to go.

Comment: ?? They'd be rows with that in the `select` clause too *edit* oh wait, I see